# Code throws error of 'controller with name 'aditya' not registered'

Tags: angularjs

**Html code:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="aditya"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js"><script>
```

**And calling it in controller.js file**

```
function aditya() {
console.log("Hello World from controller")}
```

Comment: can you please add some more description ?

Comment: can you add the code of your controller?

Answer (score 0):

> I think your controller name does not match with controller you have assigned in js

```
angular.module('aditya', function (){
   function your_function_name() {
     console.log('Hello world from controller')
   }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

**Causes for this error can be:**

1. Your reference to the controller has a typo. For example, in the
   `ngController` directive attribute, in a component definition's
   controller property, or in the call to `$controller()`.
2. You have not
   registered the controller (neither via Module.controller nor
   `$controllerProvider.register()`.
3. You have a typo in the registered
   controller name.

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Controller</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>

        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="aditya">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

controller.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
    mainApp.controller('aditya', function($scope) {
        console.log("Hello World from controller");
    });
```

---

Update

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Controller</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
            mainApp.controller('aditya', function($scope) {
                $scope.test = "Controller Testing";
                console.log("Hello World from controller");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
        
        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="aditya">
          {{test}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still same error + {{test}} is coming written below angular js sample app

Comment: when you click on `Run code snippet` then you found such error?

Comment: After running, on console of tools in browser. To see if it is connected

Comment: what code you use, please update in question. In my system its perfectly running and here (StackOverflow) also.

can you check angular library is properly loaded in your browser or not?

Comment: How to load angular library in browser ?

Comment: you can verify through debug developer tool of the browser. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools. also, check your console has any error about an angular library.